# I need to install Skype, how can I do it?

Tags: software-installation, skype

I use skype to teach on the weekends, because that is what my company requests as it offers screen sharing allowing my students to see their lessons. Has anyone had success installing and using skype on this os? If so, I need guidance.

Answer (score 1):

very easy: go to the ubuntu softwarecenter and search for Skype.